# Connecting a 18 gauge wire to a small housing

Tags: sensor, connector, interface

I'm using a sensor that has a specific connector, which outputs signal with 18-gauge wires, such as these:

[image]

And I need to connect it to standard male header pins, where cables such as these would connect to (sorry, I don't know the name in english):

[image]

The sensor is going to be connected to a board in an UAV, so the connection needs to be firm, as the UAV would be flying around. I will also need to power the sensor from the board, so there would be:

- A ground and a output wire from the sensor to the board
- A ground and an +5V wire from the board to the sensor
- The sensor wires are all 18-gauge, and the board housings are all smaller (same size as in the picture)

  Here are some ideas I've had:

*Make a separate adaptation board and use a [phoenix-type](http://www.softcomelectro.ru/images/icon/22707_1000_int_04.jpg) connector.*

This board would have a 3-pin female cable such as the picture above, and that would go into the board.

*Use some sort of [molex-type](http://i01.i.aliimg.com/img/pb/901/774/458/458774901_813.jpg) connector.*

This would have no board, but I'm not too familiar with making these types of connections.

So I would like inputs on my ideas to make this interface, as well as your own ideas that would allow me to make a stable connection occupying as little space as possible.

Please let me know if I'm not clear on anything.

EDIT: Here's a schematic for clarity. I'm just looking for suggestions on how to do the **?** part, in order for a secure and safe connection. I am also not sure if it's good practice to connect both grounds on the board or if I can just get away with one.

[image]

Comment: Will the sensor wires plug directly into the UAV board or are you wanting to bring wires out of the sensor and wires out of the board, connecting in the middle?  If directly into the board, do you want the ends of the sensor wires to terminate male or female?

Comment: Can't you just solder the connector on? Cover the joints with heat-shrink...can't imagine anything smaller or simpler.

Comment: @mikeY: I am inclined to do it on a board. If on a board, I don't know how I am going to attach them, and want suggestions on that. If not on a board, then I have no idea how I would work that, and would also like suggestions =S

Comment: @Phil: I can't solder directly to the board, and I would also want to be able to remove the sensor from the board. Sorry if  I misunderstood your suggestion

Comment: @triplebig no, I mean solder the sensor to the connector, which then connects the board. Ostensibly the problem here is that you can't find a connector that will take wires as fat as 18 ga, so solder thinner wires on the fat wires, and then the thinner wires fit in the connector.

Comment: Although, I do wonder why a sensor would have 18 ga wires if it didn't need them, such as to carry high currents, or because the wire resistance will render measurements wrong, in which case terminating the thing with such a tiny connector is probably not a great idea.

Comment: The connector in the 2nd photo is a female .100" header connector, BTW.

Answer (score 1):

I think all you want to do is solder some male header pins on the wires out of your sensor, and then make a connector wire for your board(s) with some female pins soldered on both ends.  Maybe one end of the connector has a solid block of pins and the other end is split to hook up in two places.

I think you are overthinking it and making it more difficult than it really is.  I think regular solderable header pins should be sturdy enough for a UAV.  You could go all Molex or something but I don't think you need to.